# How do floats affect the flow of a paragraph?

Tags: floats, sectioning, captions, positioning, paragraphs

I've been working on my own custom template but I ran into a behavior I don't understand. Why are some paragraphs indented with a tab? I think it has something to do with floats breaking the *flow* of a paragraph.

I got really frustrated dealing with figures and all my problems seem to be solved by the `float` package. But if I use it the paragraph after the float gets indented. I found a way to stop this behavior but I want to understand why it is there in the first place. I don't know how to put any better than to describe it as the *flow*... Let's call it that. I assume this behavior, this indenting has a reason, I want to understand it.

See how I use `H`:

```latex
\section{Figures}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{images/example.jpg}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[1]
```

This is the resulting pdf; The paragraph after the figure is indented by a tab.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is probably  caused by use figure float placement option `[H]`. Replace it for example with `[ht]` and see difference. However, if image is placed between two paragraphs, this is  expected behavior.

Comment: I tried using `ht`, `!ht`, `h`, and `!h` but it always put the float (figure) inside one of the paragraphs and not between them. With inside I mean, it just spitted it. There was no obvious line break or anything, Latex just decided it would split there. @Zarko

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear, what you expected. If you not decide differently, all paragraphs start with indentation of the first line.  If you not like this, than try to add to document preamble `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` or insert before to paragraph which follows image  `\noindent`

Comment: @Zarko using a `h` float you would get no new paragraph  and no indent here, similarly if you just used `center`. The paragraph indent is a feature of `H`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\section{Figures}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=10pt,width=200pt]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=10pt,width=200pt]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{center}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=10pt,width=200pt]{example-image}
\end{center}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

It appears to be a mis-feature in the float package `[H]` you could report it but changing things after all these years might be tricky.

You get no paragraph if you  use a `h` float as in the second image. If you want the image not to move in any circumsance there are few cases where you really need to use `figure` to allow it to move then `[H]` to stop it, you can simply not use `figure` at all. A display environment such as `center` will also correctly interupt a paragraph without causing a new paragraph indent in the following text as seen in the third image.